# What is the best practice for centralized user management?

Tags: c#, php, design-patterns

My SaaS application is spanned across multiple platforms and I need to sync the user data acrooss them all:  We have the website which is Drupal and the application server itself which is .NET (C#). I want users that register to the website to use the same credentials for the RIA, so I'm thinking of using a central user management db and software.

Is there a service or built software I can use? What is the best practice for that design, or am I looking at it all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP) is what you're looking for.